# Returning a non-conflicting selection

Tags: python-3.x, sorting, conflict

i am stuck on my code that i am working on and i need some help.
now imagine if you have a list:

```
[(1,5,7),(2,1,4),(3,0,3),(4,6,10),(5,7,9)]
```

each one represent a node (ID , start time, finish time)
now i need my output to be:

```
[(1,5,7),(2,1,4),(5,7,9)]
```

so that there is no confliction between times.
my code prints:

```
[(1,5,7),(2,1,4),(3,0,3),(5,7,9)]
```

and as you can see (3,0,3) conflicts with (2,1,4)

Comment: i made 2 lists original list and selected list
original:

    `[(1,5,7),(2,1,4),(3,0,3),(4,6,10),(5,7,9)]`

selected:

     `[(1,5,7)]`
then i for looped them 2 times to check with a flag. 
not sure if that the right thing to do or not.

Comment: Post your code as well

Comment: a=0
selected_list=[original[0]]
for i in original:
    while a+1 != len(sorted_list):
        if selected_list[0]._finish_time<= original[a+1]._start_time 
            or selected_list[0]._start_time >= 
            original[a+1]._finish_time:
                selected_list.append(sorted_list[a+1])
            a+=1
            else:
                a+=1
                pass
    selected_list = list(set(selected_list))
    selected_list = sorted(selected_list, key=lambda x: x._finish_time - x._start_time)
    return selected_list

Comment: Returns a non-conflicting selection of jobs from the original list, i.e. jobs are considered in order, each job is included if and only if it doesn't conflict with previously chosen jobs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initialise an empty list for storing busy times. 
Use a for loop and go through the list. 
When you get the item: 1,5,7. You add all the times between 5 and 7 to that busy times list. So busy times now has 5,6,7.

For each one those node, check if the interval of numbers exist in the busylist. If they don't add them to your non-conflicing selection list, and add those numbers to your busy list.